# ogr2ogr cannot import .osm.pbf file to PostGIS

Tags: postgis, ogr2ogr, ogrinfo

I'm trying to import a multipolygon layer from "colorado-latest.osm.pbf" into PostGIS. GDAL 2.4.2 has been installed in a Ubuntu system. However, whenever I'm trying to import the osm.pbf file, I get this error:

```
ogr2ogr -where "building LIKE'%'" -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=XXXXXX.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com port=5432 user='postgres' password='XXXXXX' dbname='postgres'" colorado_latest.osm.pbf multipolygons

FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `colorado_latest.osm.pbf' with the following drivers.
  -> PCIDSK
  -> netCDF
  -> JP2OpenJPEG
  -> PDF
  -> MBTiles
  -> EEDA
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> Map.....
.........
```

The ogrinfo query also yield the same error:

```
ogrinfo -ro -geom=NO -sql "select * from multipolygons where osm_id = '253750'" colorado_latest.osm.pbf

FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `colorado_latest.osm.pbf' with the following drivers.
  -> PCIDSK
  -> netCDF
  -> JP2OpenJPEG
  -> PDF
  -> MBTiles
  -> EEDA
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> Map.....
.........
```

I'm using GDAL 2.4.2 which supports osm.pbf. I have SQLite installed. ogrinfo --formats also gives a list of formats which contains OSM. I have checked the /usr/share/gdal/osmconf.ini file. Its the same as default. The PostGIS extensions are available in the database and previously I have imported shapefiles into the same.

What do I need to correct here?

Comment: If you have downloaded data from geofabrik.de I suggest to have a cup of coffee, check the spelling, and have a try with `colorado-latest.osm.pbf`

Comment: @user30184 Thanks indeed ! That was something ! In addition compiling from source code helped following https://developernote.com/2016/10/compiling-gdal-on-ubuntu-linux-with-sql-support/ with sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename the original file name as follows (and update the code):

colorado_latest.osm.pbf -> colorado_latest.pbf

(thus removing the '.osm')

also, as suggested in the comments, check that underscore, usually data downloaded from geofabrik are like 'colorado-latest.osm.pbf'